# Login to manager of piranhacms hosted in docker behind nginx on ubuntu (aspnet core 6)

Tags: asp.net-core, piranha-cms

Does anyone has experience hosting piranha on ubuntu in a docker container behind nginx?

The frontend is fine, everything works smooth. But the manager is not working for me. It has something to do with the login. First i saw error 502 after login (failed login was working with correct error message, so the post itself is working). I changed the login not to do the local redirect but returning the page. No error message, so i guess the login data was fine, but somehow i am still not logged in.

The only cookie i see is the antoforgery. Someone has an idea, the is no error message in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that aspnet core identity created a cookie larger then nginx accept in proxy communication.

I increase the buffers, but this did not work for me. There are a lot of article about it, but nothing worked.

So i decided to reduce the header sent. The application configuration has been changed to manage the identity in a different way. More information in memory but smaller cookie.